# Can you have an infinite descending chain of dual spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, examples-counterexamples, normed-spaces, dual-spaces

If a Banach space $X$ is not reflexive, then you have an infinite ascending chain of (continuous) dual spaces: $X’$, $X’’$, $X’’’$, etc.  None of these are isomorphic to each other or to $X$.

My question is, can you have an infinite descending sequence of dual spaces?  That is, is it possible for $X$ to be isomorphic to the dual space of some space $X_1$, which is isomorphic to the dual space of some space $X_2$, etc., such that none of these spaces are isomorphic to each other or to $X$?  Or must the chain always stop at some space which is not isomorphic to any dual space?

Comment: There is no *natural* embedding $X\hookrightarrow X'$. Do you mean the chain $X\hookrightarrow X'' \hookrightarrow X^{(4)} \hookrightarrow  \cdots$? By tranposition you then get a chain $X'\leftarrow X^{(3)} \leftarrow X^{(5)} \leftarrow \cdots$.

Comment: A Banach space always has a natural embedding into its double dual. So, in some sense, double dual is always at lease as large as the original space.

Comment: @Jochen I’m not talking about embeddings at all.  I just meant ascending in the sense that $X’$ is the dual of $X$, $X’’$ is the dual of $X’$, etc.  And descending in the sense that $X$ is the dual of $X_1$, which is the dual of $X_2$, etc.

Comment: This is an interesting question but i would expect an example to be quite complicated.

Comment: Okay, I understand your question, now. The claim you make, that for a non-rflexive Banach spaces all iterated duals are non-isomorphic, is wrong. The infamous *James space* $J$ is not reflexive but isomorphic to its second dual. (Reflexivity means that the canonical embedding $X\to X''$, $x\mapsto \delta_x$ is an isomorphism but NOT that there is some isomorphism.)